# Moving viewports lost data in Sencha Architect 3

Tags: extjs, hide, show, viewport, destroy

I am a beginner in Sencha Architect 3.0 and I would be grateful if someone could help me with a problema that I have.
    I have two viewports (viewport A and viewport B) and in these viewports I have a button to move from viewport A to viewport B and viceversa.
    The problem is that if I move from viewport A to viewpor B and then from viewport B to viewport A, I lost the data inserted in viewport A (using .destroy() and .create() function).
    I have tried using .hide() and .show() functions but it does not work.
    I hope you could help me,
Gaston.